# MySQL Workbench - Tables not appearing in EER diagram after model sync

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just got started with Laravel and by default it has some migrations that need to be executed. The migrations created the tables correctly in my database and I synchronized my model so that I can work with those tables in Workbench.

In the overview, I can see all the tables.

[image]

But on the EER Diagram I can only see the table I created via Workbench itself.

[image]

What can I do to make the other tables appear on the EER Diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop down the table from the left (list of tables) to the EER diagram. To hide it it's an option when you right click on a table.